# Error message location in Python vs cmd

Tags: python, mysql

Platform

- Win10
- Python3.6

My code to use mysql:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "mysql -uroot -proot -Dtest <C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.sql"

status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)

print(output)
```

my test.sql is

```
SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts;
SELECT "中" FROM wp_posts limit 1;
SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts123;
```

The result from the Python code is:

[image]

The result from `cmd` is:

[image]

**Question:** Why is the error message in a different position?